# iPhone Dev: multiple XIB to support orientation like multiple languages?

Tags: iphone, xib, uiinterfaceorientation

I've just discovered multiple xib for languages ui support, I'm very excited because is simpler than I expected.
Now I was wondering if it's possible to apply same method to have multiple xib for different orientation simply creating different folders in project containing a xib with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that simple. You *can* do that to have multiple NIBs for iPad and iPhone, but for orientations, you have to manually reload the NIB both at initialization (unless you always load at a constant orientation), *and* during a RotationToInterfaceOrientation event.

Comment: thanks Brad, I already do that, it would be grateful if were possible but thanks for saving my time from unuseful google search ;)